# Windows 7: Event Viewer Issue (log on codes and workstation name query)

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, login

I am using a laptop for home use. I am not connected to a server or anything, just the home wifi.

Today I was looking in the event viewer and I saw quite a lot of log ons with numbers, 2,3,5 or 7. Are these all normal enough? I was using the computer at the time so I doubt someone was logging in 'remotely' while I was on it. Is it normal on start up, and log in (using password) etc to see for example log on 2, then a few seconds later log on 3, 5 or 7(when I unlock the screen after the computer has been idle)?

Also, something more worrying is how my girlfriend's name appears at times in the Workstation name. 
We both have our own laptops with just 1 profile, on my laptop under my name and on hers under her name.

However, her workstation shows up on mine sometimes which I do not understand. When I start up my computer there is just one user profile (mine) and I put in my password. Even when she uses my computer she is still connecting as me so I don't understand how her name would appear in workstation name. Should I be worried about this or is this just her computer connecting to the same wifi network or something? We dont have file sharing or anything like that enabled.

Malware bytes has shown the usual malware stuff PUP.OPTIONAL.CONDUIT etc so I don't think this is the problem: Here is an example of one of the logs. I have removed her name and my IP:

An account was successfully logged on.

```
Subject:
Security ID: NULL SID
Account Name: -
Account Domain: -
Logon ID: 0x0

Logon Type: 3

New Logon:
Security ID: ANONYMOUS LOGON
Account Name: ANONYMOUS LOGON
Account Domain: NT AUTHORITY
Logon ID: 0xe56308
Logon GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
Process ID: 0x0
Process Name: -

Network Information:
Workstation Name: ******(GIRLFRIENDS NAME)
Source Network Address: ************
Source Port: 49744

Detailed Authentication Information:
Logon Process: NtLmSsp 
Authentication Package: NTLM
Transited Services: -
Package Name (NTLM only): NTLM V1
Key Length: 128
```